# Integrate: $\int_{a - i\infty}^{a + i\infty} \frac{e^{tz}}{z^2 + p^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Q. Show that : $$\int_{a - i\infty}^{a + i\infty} \frac{e^{tz}}{z^2 + p^2}dz = \frac{\sin pt}{p}$$

I considered the following contour
[image]
$$\int_\Gamma \frac{e^{tz}}{z^2 + p^2}dz + \int_{a - i\infty}^{a + i\infty} \frac{e^{tz}}{z^2 + p^2}dz  = 2 \pi i (\text{Residue}[f(z), z=ip] + \text{Residue}[f(z), z=ip]) \; \; \; \;\; \;(1)$$
The first integral goes to zero. 
$$\text{Residue}[f(z), z=ip]  + \text{Residue}[f(z), z=-ip]= \frac{\sin (pt)}{p} \hspace{1cm} (2)$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get 
$$\int_{a - i\infty}^{a + i\infty} \frac{e^{tz}}{z^2 + p^2}dz = 2 \pi i \frac{\sin pt}{p}$$

Did I make any mistake or (answer according to) question is wrong?

Comment: Do we have to guess what $\,\Gamma\,$ is ? Because my guess is that it is a circle centered at the origin and containing in its interior the point $\,ip\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I uploaded the picture of the contour.

Comment: It's no clear why you get the first integral goes to zero.

Comment: It's wrong to write $\int_{\Gamma} + \int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}$, it should be $\int_{a-iU}^{a+iU}$ for some $U$ which goes to infinity as the radius goes to infinity - basically, $U=\sqrt{R^2-a^2}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see, how do suggest it then? I thought it would be similar to Jordan's lemma

Comment: You might be right that the first integral goes to zero, I just didn't see it as obvious, so you need to explain why it is true.  The second comment was just a quibble.

Comment: What is the relation between $a$ and $p$?

Comment: @vesszabo not given, i suppose both $\in \Bbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use the contour shown in the figure.  I prefer going, from the top of the vertical line at $a+i R$, to the left horizontally to $z=i R$, and then going in a semicircular arc between $\theta \in [\pi/2,3 \pi/2]$.  In this case, the integral over the horizontal portion to the left goes as

$$\frac{e^{i R t}}{R^2-p^2} \frac{1-e^{a t}}{t} $$

as $R \to \infty$.  We get a similar expression for the horizontal segment at $z=-i R$.

It then becomes crystal clear that the integral along the circular arc vanishes, because the integral there looks like

$$i R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{R t \cos{\theta}} e^{i R \sin{\theta}}}{R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+p^2}$$

The magnitude of this integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$ because the cosine term is negative over the integration region. So, at least along this contour, the integral vanishes.

Comment: so is final answer $2 \pi i \frac{\sin pt}{p}$ ??

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: yes.

Comment: all right thanks!!! ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: I've never seen you add those horizontal segments before when evaluating an inverse Laplace transform. And I've never seen the Bromwich contour drawn that way. But it was never obvious to me why the integral would go to zero along the arc if the arc extended into the 1st and 4th quadrants. Why is your contour not standard?

Comment: @randomvariable: yeah, I don't know.  I just thought it was self-evident.  Silly me.

Comment: Have you seen the Bromwich contour drawn like that anywhere? It's like when someone says that some contour integral goes to zero around a half-circle in the upper-half plane of infinite radius when the way to show that it does uses a rectangle. Why not just use the rectangle in the first place?

Comment: @RandomVariable: Honestly, I had never seen it before.  It just made sense to me because, as you said, the circular contour crept into the 1st and 4th quadrants, not good.  Could you use a rectangle?  Properly outfitted so that the integral does not blow up along it, why not?  I just think that the circle is most convenient.

Comment: I was not saying to use a rectangle here. But what you've shown is not only does it go to zero around your augmented contour, it also goes to zero around an arc that leaks into the first and 4th quadrants, right?

Comment: @RandomVariable: Right, that was the entire idea.  As you said, I was never comfortable with the standard contour that Mula showed because the cosine term in the exponential is positive there.  With the augmented piece, for each point  on that augmented piece, only the imaginary part of the exponential varies as $R \to \infty$.  Then again, now that I think of it, I think that using a fully rectangular contour would cause difficulties: for example, how does the *other* vertical segment behave?